# Tooltip text changing depending on which words are moused over in text box?

Tags: java, swing, text, tooltip

Is it possible to make it so that the tooltip displayed will change when over certain keywords inside of some swing object? The content will be completely defined by the code so I could use text positioning if that would help. Thanks

Edit:

Okay, specifically what I would be doing is creating a custom display box for text to use as a combat log. This will be overtop my animations, a hud if you will. What I am thinking, is that I can use a tooltip to display the attributes behind combat calculations, while de-cluttering the log for people who know how things work already.

Comment: Can you give some example? Are you in someway talking about setting a tooltip to a Label containing text?

Comment: Edited my above post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `getToolTipText(...)`. Simple example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;


public class ToolTipPanel extends JPanel
{
    public ToolTipPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 200) );
        setToolTipText("");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( Color.red );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 200);
        g.setColor( Color.blue );
        g.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 200);
    }

    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getX() < 100)
            return "red";
        else
            return "blue";
    }

    public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        p.y += 15;
        return p;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.getContentPane().add( new ToolTipPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

With a text component you would need to use the mouse point and the getViewToModel() method to get the text from the Document.